# How to store words from string which are space seperated?

Tags: c#

I want to take  some number as input from the user, And the numbers are space seperated.How can I break that string into single word and store each number in a single variable . I am a bit confuse in using read() or readLine() statements.

The User Interface is

Enter Numbers: 5 4 3 2

I want to get these numbers.

Comment: readline -> split on space -> use linq select with int.parse | plenty of tutorials are available on web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do it

```
var Result = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList(); // 5 4 3 2

//store each number in a single variable
int i1 = Result[0]; //5
int i2 = Result[1]; //4
int i3 = Result[2]; //3
int i4 = Result[3]; //2
```